# Is there a way to use prestashop core controllers in modules without using the override?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to override one core controller, but instead of changing/placing it in override folder, I want to provide my new version of the controller directly from the module. In this way, the  core files will not be affect when upgrading.. can this be done?

I have tried a couple of times, but it gives me 404 error when requiring the file.

Any suggestions? Has anyone done this with prestashop.. i did this countless of times in wordpress and it works like a charm.. but no luck with prestashop so far.. i am working with v.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.. as no one was here to answer.. this is for future reference should someone bump into the same situation.. Here is what I did:

I created an override folder within my module folder, I reconstructed the files so that the file structure follows that of prestashop.. bacuase I have to work on 2 core file.. one Cart.php in classes folder and the other Cartcontroller.php in controllers folder:

- my_modulename/class/Cart.php
- my_modulename/controllers/Cartcontroller.php

  Then I read in the prestashop forum that you have to make the changes within the main override files then copy the override codes to its counterpart over at the module/override.. to prevent the module to be reset every time changes is made.

So far, it has work fine, but not without much difficutly.

I hope this help someone down the road.